# django-jquery doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jquery, django

I have a server running with Django 1.6 framework. It runs without any problems as far as I can tell, and even django-jquery should be working properly since everything points that way. I am actually able to load jquery.js and my own js file into the browser. When I inspect the code of my website I can click the links to each of the javascript files and SEE the code, but for some reason my code isn't firing.

I am very new to the Django framework, but like I said, as far as I can tell everything on the Django side seems to be working properly.

This is how the links to the js files look in the code in my browser:

```
<script type='javascript' src='/static/js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='javascript' src='/static/js/myscript.js'></script>
```

And I can actually click the links to the scripts and view the code in them so they should be loaded properly. I haven't changed the code in the jquery.js file, it's still the same it was when I installed django-jquery using `pip install django-jquery`. The code in myscript.js is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
});
```

Which seems like it should be working fine as well. I am completely stumped and I have zero clue what I should do to get this to work. It probably is something simple and completely stupid of me to miss, but I have been battling this problem for the past few hours now and I have no idea how to go about this. Any help would very greatly appreciated...

**EDIT**
Just to be sure the django-jquery supplied code wasn't the problem, I tried to update the code in the current jquery.js file to the latest jquery release code (2.0.3 as of this moment) which didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `type='javascript'` to `type='text/javascript'`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I was having this much trouble with something I have never had trouble with before. I always used `javascript` instead of `text/javascript` without errors. Anyway, like I said it would be, it was something incredibly simple that I overlooked. Thanks for pointing it out for me.

Comment: You are welcome. P.S never hard code static urls in django. Use [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL) or use [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:templatetag-staticfiles-static) template tag. More information about this is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: I always do, but it just turns out looking like a hard-coded url in the browser.